# WPF/XAML using TreeViewItems in a TreeView with Databinding and advanced templates

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, binding, treeview

I'm pretty new to XAML and to databinding, so hopefully this will be an easy question to someone out there...

I'm trying to build a TreeView using data binding that has a structure similar to this:

- Category

  - Item Name
  - Item Name
- Category

  - Item Name

So far, so good--I can do that.  Next, I want to be able to expand the Item node and show details about that item.  This works fine when I build the tree manually in the code-behind, but I want to use data binding instead.  I ALMOST have this working, but as it is now, either I can't select the node OR I can't get the node to behave like a TreeViewItem where it shows just the item name when it is collapsed and can expand to show more--in my case a custom defined grid with data on it.

Here's a simplified sample of my XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate">
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=ItemName}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Price" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Qty on Hand" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Qty}"/>
        </Grid>
    </TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CategoryDataTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Based on this simplified example, the object that was defined in the code-behind would be something like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items {get; private set;}
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    //constructor and methods here
}
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName {get; private set;}
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public string Description {get; private set; }
    public int Qty {get; set;}

    //constructor and methods here
}
```

After reading [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557787/wpf-xaml-treeview-doesnt-hightlight-nodes-after-binding) on stackoverflow, I can see that you cannot have your template be a TreeViewItem if you want to select the node.  I tried getting rid of the TreeViewItem tag and going straight to the Grid which allows me to select the node, but now I can't collapse the node down to just the ItemName (header text).

I feel like it's darn close... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you want is to make an Item *look like it has more child nodes*, even though its only "child" is itself, presented with more info?

Well, the most correct way of doing that might be to use an expander in ItemDataTemplate, like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate">
    <Expander Header="{Binding Path=ItemName}" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ...
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ...

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Price" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>

            <TextBlock ...
        </Grid>
    </TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

The expander doesn't look exactly like a standard TreeViewItem, but that can be fixed by making your own Template for the Expander.

Now, a slightly more hacky way of doing it would be to have a list of Items in the Item class, where each Item exposes itself as the only list element. Then, ItemDataTemplate would need to be a HierarchicalDataTemplate which referenced another, more detailed, "ItemDetailsTemlate":

```
public class Item
{
    ...

    public List<Item> InfoWrapper
    {
        get { return new List<Item>() { this }; }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDetailsTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            ...
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            ...

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Price" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>

        <TextBlock ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InfoWrapper}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDetailsTemplate}" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Your "more hacky way of doing it" does EXACTLY what I want--THANKS!  I also like your suggestion of using an expander and making it look and feel like a TreeViewItem with a template--I'll have to dig around a bit to see how to do that.  I agree that the expander is probably a more correct way to do it, so if I can figure that out, I'll probably switch to that method.